# ArcMap fails to add rasters to mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, mosaic-dataset

I couldn’t figure out why ArcMap 10.3 fails to add rasters to the mosaic dataset. The following messages are displayed in the results

```
Image server is not supported with the current license
Server object instance creation failed on machine
Error: 80040213: configuration rastercommander.Imageserver cannot be started
Error: 8004206f: could not initialize the mosaic dataset's parallel processing engine
Error: 8004204b: Cannot synchronize mosaic dataset items associated with the specified raster type instance.
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Walk through the following steps:

1. `Environment Settings (in tool's dialog box) > Parallel Processing`.
2. Set the `parallel processing factor` as 0 (zero).

Comment: Welcome to GIS.stackexchange, can you provide a reference to your answer?

Comment: Thanks It worked fine with me Seting the parallel processing factor as 0 (zero)